# How to auto synchronize data in Mysql to Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, indexer

How to synchronize Sphinx data with MySQL automatically when new data added in MySQL

Any one suggest me I am using `Sphinxql` using `PHP`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [RT-indexes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/rt-overview.html). For example when you add new record to the database, you have to add the same record to the sphinx RT-index at once.